# How do we translate a French master in English (UK)?

Tags: british-english, translation

I would like to know how the UK equivalent/translation for a French student who is BAC+5 and going to get his engineering degree. Is it under/post/graduate?

Comment: do you have any further questions on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_nationale_sup%C3%A9rieure_d%27ing%C3%A9nieurs_de_Caen) the BAC + 5 is seen as equivalent to a [Masters in Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Science), also known as 'MSc.' in the UK.  A Master's degree qualification is a postgraduate qualification.

A potentially useful article for you would be the Wikipedia page for [National Qualifications Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Qualifications_Framework). The UK education system categorizes qualifications in 8 'levels'.  The BAC + 5 is level 7.  If you have a Masters in the UK is it assumed you completed previous study and attained at a bachelor's degree (or equivalent) so it is offered as a postgraduate degree.  Masters programs are also known as 'graduate' degrees which is an import from US English.

[image: Wiki Image of UK Degree qualifications]

Comment: Please note, that that the National Qualifications Framework (NQF) was replaced by the Qualifications and Credit Framework (QCF) in 2010.  However, the article for NQF has a more helpful table in it which will be the same as QCF.  The fourth link is to a diagram describing QCF.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not a student is an undergraduate or postgraduate depends on whether they have already got a degree.  Someone working towards their first degree is an undergraduate.  Someone who already has a degree and is working towards a higher degree is a postgraduate.

I don't know if 'is BAC+5' means this person already has a degree or not but presumably you can work out the right word from the above.

Comment: _"...depends on whether they have already got a degree"_ ...from a college or university. (Non high-school)  In the U.S. at least.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: In America we normally talk about four "levels" of degree: associate, bachelor, master, and doctor. When you don't yet have a bachelors, you are said to be "undergraduate". An associates degree typically requires 2 years of study, and each higher level degree 2 more years over the previous.

Comment: One tag onto this is that many (most?) people who get a bachelor's degree do so without getting an associate's degree first - they complete a single four year program for the bachelor's degree.  This happens at the post-graduate level also, but getting a master's before the PhD (doctorate) is more common than getting an associate's degree before going for a bachelor's.

Comment: @Adam Yes, excellent point. Common tracks are AA and done; BS and done; BS -> MS and done; BS -> MS -> PhD. Some do AA -> BS, then maybe go further or maybe not, but I think that's relatively rare.